# Limit of an integral in deriving formula for arc-length

Tags: integration, curves, arc-length

I have struggle understanding a certain step in a proof. Let $\boldsymbol{g}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $\int_a^b\boldsymbol{g}:=\left[\int_a^bg_1,\, \dots\,,\int_a^bg_n \right]^T$.

At a point in the proof, it is used that

\begin{equation*}
\Vert\boldsymbol{g}'(t)\Vert = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h}\Vert\boldsymbol{g}'(u)\Vert du
\end{equation*}

Could someone please explain why this is true?

Comment: What's the norm $||\cdot||$ ?

Comment: @Carot Presumably the Euclidean norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention it's the Euclidian norm.